# Simple .bat file opens and closes without running

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, macros

I have a very simple .bat file to run an access macro overnight.

```
"Subrogation Management Reports.accdb" /x mcoDailyDiaryDetail
```

On my machine it will open run the macro and close correctly.  On 2 of my co-worker's machines, however, the .bat file will open and close instantly without actually running the macro.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting this?  I don't have a lot of experience with .bat files and can't seem to find the issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Add `pause` at the end of the file on a new line, so it doesn't close, and read any errors it might be showing

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying the bat file, just open a CMD prompt (start > run > CMD) and type:

```
call c:\pathtobatfile.bat
```

It will run the bat file in the currently open Window and will display any errors you may come across.

Answer (score 1):

If @Slav's suggestion does not change the batch file's behavior (i.e., it appears to ignore the PAUSE) you might check the file's encoding. On my version of Windows, a file containing just the single line
    PAUSE
will open and close without any apparent feedback if encoded as UTF-16. A file containing only the same line encoded as ASCII gives the expected behavior (outputs "Press any key to continue...")

Answer (score 1):

the problem is space in command path

```
%EXECCMD% %VMARGS% -launchcommand "%EXECCMD% %VMARGS% %*" -launchscript %0 %*
```

add quoters like this to solve it

```
"%EXECCMD%" %VMARGS% -launchcommand "%EXECCMD% %VMARGS% %*" -launchscript %0 %*
```

Comment: Yeah, this saved my day! By adding the quotation marks, spaces in the windows path can be correctly handled.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Application control, if you used in any Antivirus.
Application control will block command processor.

or Exclude/Allow this bat file in application control.

Answer (score -2):

Add `pause` to the end of your batch file. It will prompt you `Press any key to continue...` and when you press a key it will close.

Comment: We appreciate your attempt to contribute, but if you answer a question this old, your answer should at least add something useful instead of just repeating a [nearly eight years old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23366562/2152082)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).